# Proguard keep classmembers

Tags: android, json, serialization, field, proguard

How can I tell proguard to keep my classmembers?

I need them for JSON compatibility...

This is my class:

```
package com.tools.app.holiday;

public class Holiday {  

    private String name;

    private Calendar dateFrom = Calendar.getInstance();

    private Calendar dateTo = Calendar.getInstance();

    ...
```

I already tried, but it doesnt work...

```
-keepclassmembers class com.tools.app.holiday.Holiday 

-keepclassmembers class com.tools.app.holiday.Holiday *{
    private String name;    
    private Calendar dateFrom;
    private Calendar dateTo;
}
```

I also implemented serialisable and did:

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
```

But it all doesn't keep my member names. Proguard always changes ist to a, b, c :-(
What am I missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All class names must be fully qualified:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.tools.app.holiday.Holiday {
    private java.lang.String name;    
    private java.util.Calendar dateFrom;
    private java.util.Calendar dateTo;
}
```

By default, ProGuard even prints out messages if you forget this.

Comment: Do you have to specify each field explicitly? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365021/how-to-tell-proguard-to-keep-private-fields-without-specifying-each-field