# How to tell ProGuard to keep private fields without specifying each field

Tags: java, android, proguard

This is my class:

```
package com.tools.app.holiday;

public class Holiday {  

    private String name;

    private Calendar dateFrom = Calendar.getInstance();

    private Calendar dateTo = Calendar.getInstance();

    ...
```

I can keep these private fields by putting the following in my ProGuard rules file:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.tools.app.holiday.Holiday {
    private java.lang.String name;    
    private java.util.Calendar dateFrom;
    private java.util.Calendar dateTo;
}
```

But I'd prefer not to have to specify each field individually. How can I do this?

P.S. I stole most of this from [Proguard keep classmembers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418733/proguard-keep-classmembers) because that question was close to what I'm asking.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

According to [ProGuard documenation](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#classspecification) the wildcard `<fields>` matches any field. Thus it should be something like:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.tools.app.holiday.Holiday {
    private <fields>;    
}
```

If you want to preserve private fields in all classes use:

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
    private <fields>;    
}
```

Comment: How about `-keepclasseswithmembers class * { @com.activeandroid.annotation.Column <fields>; }`