# Obfuscate private fields using ProGuard

Tags: java, android, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

I'm using ProGuard in AndroidStudio 1.2.1.1 with Gradle 1.2.3.

My Gradle's release build is configured like so:

```
minifyEnabled true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
shrinkResources true
```

I would like the private fields of classes to be obfuscated.

Here is my proguard config file (after many tries) as of now:

```
-allowaccessmodification
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-repackageclasses ''
-verbose
[...]
```

But I end up, after decompiling with `androdd` from AndroidGuard, with:

```
private com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
```

I know the use of this obfuscation is limited, but I would like `googleApiClient` to be renamed by ProGuard. How to do so?

Here is the [refcard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/refcard.html).

Is there any way to do the opposite of `-keepclassmembernames`?

Comment: is googleApiClient the only unobfuscated field or is it the same for all fields?

Comment: I would like this for all private fields.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Getting from this:
[How to tell ProGuard to keep private fields without specifying each field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365021/how-to-tell-proguard-to-keep-private-fields-without-specifying-each-field)

> According to [ProGuard documenation](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#classspecification) the wildcard  matches any
>   field.

Top of that, You can use  negators (!). 
(http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#manual/usage.html)

> Attribute names can contain ?, *, and ** wildcards, and they can be
>   preceded by the ! negator.

I am not so experienced in this field, so rather it is a guess, but easier to write in a new comment. Something like this should do the job (NOT TESTED):

```
-keepclassmembers class * { //should find all classes 
    !private <fields>;    
    <methods>;
    <init>; //and keep every field, method, constructor apart from private fields
}
```

May be you can use like this, but do not sure how it works with a negator first:

```
-keepclassmembers class * { //should find all classes 
    !private <fields>;    
    *; //should exclude everything except private fields, which should be obfuscated.
}
```

Comment: I used `-keepclassmembers class my.package { !private <fields>; protected <field>; public <fields>; <methods>; }` and got what I wanted: fields with names `a`, `b`, `c` etc. I knew this has to do with negators, thanks for leading me to the right usage. I will refine for my personal usage, but that is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Here is my final ProGuard file that works bug Android bug #78377: https://gist.github.com/shkschneider/a1c81780cd1f35a7037d

Comment: Thank you for your response and for the reward! 

I am glad that you worked out based on my hints, also thanks for putting to github, it was a good experience for me also.