# How to not obfuscate interface methods & its parameters using Proguard in Android?

Tags: android, obfuscation, android-proguard

I have the following code:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void method1(Integer marks) {

    }

    private String method3(String name){

    }
    public interface interface1 {
        void method4(Integer ID);
        void method5(Integer rate, boolean status);
    }
}
```

I have used progaurd-rules.pro

```
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

-keepparameternames

-keep public class *
-keepclassmembers public class *{
   public *;
 }
-keep public interface packageName.MyClass$interface1 { *; }
```

Obfuscated code as below:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void method1(Integer marks) {

    }

    private String a(String var1){

    }
    public interface interface1 {
        void method4(Integer var1);
        void method5(Integer var1, boolean var2);
    }
}
```

I want the interface methods variables (ID, rate & status) not to obfuscate. i.e as below

```
public interface interface1 {
    void method4(Integer ID);
    void method5(Integer rate, boolean status);
}
```

How can it be possible?

Comment: I am not sure if this helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526173/obfuscate-private-fields-using-proguard?rq=1

Comment: @ user3796318 Thank you. I am able to do this with classes & it's methods and fields. But got problem while handling Interface. I'm glad if you share any idea of keeping parameters inside interface.

Comment: Hi, did you solve your issue ? @Han

Comment: If you use -dontobfuscate? Or do you want only this particular method not obfuscated?

Answer (score 3):

You could keep method's arguments by adding extra flags to `-keepattributes`. They look like this:

```
-keepattributes LocalVariableTable,LocalVariableTypeTable
```

Unfortunately, this keeps arguments from obfuscation not only in the interface you want, but in the entire project. Maybe that's fine for you.

If you're using a default proguard configuration shipped along with Android SDK then you could also use a special annotation to prevent some classes from obfuscation. [Check it out](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/Keep.html).

Comment: I only want to keep var names for params in functions i have defined in interfaces, the whole other part of the project should still be obfuscated as much as possible

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface SSOListener {
    void sendDataToAnalytics(String event, JSONArray object);
}

// In my case JsonArray was obfuscated.


Solution :
-keep class org.json.JSONArray**, ** {
    protected <fields>;
    public <fields>;
    <methods>;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

```
-keepattributes LocalVariableTable,LocalVariableTypeTable
```

The above keepattributes didn't work for me. However `-keepparameternames` did. I added this to the internal Proguard config that our Android Library uses. The other non keot classes still have their params obfuscated.

Note: I'm using R8 to actually obfuscate which is the default when using the Android Gradle Plugin [since 3.4.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#3-4-0) also we are enforcing source and target compatibility to 1.8 (due to unrelated okhttp dependency)

Answer (score -1):

ProGuard uses the naming convention of Java bytecode, as seen in class file names and stacktraces. Therefore:

```
-keep public interface com.somepackage.SomeClass$someInterface {*;}
```

In case if your interface is not public.

```
-keep interface com.somepackage.SomeClass$someInterface {*;}.
```

Comment: Unfortunately parameter names of interface functions are not kept