# how to keep private members in pro-guard rules

Tags: java, android, proguard

I am trying to use Proguard to keep my private fields, but it won't work.
I stole most of this from Proguard keep classmembers because that question is similar to what I'm asking, and also followed this link [How to tell ProGuard to keep private fields without specifying each field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365021/how-to-tell-proguard-to-keep-private-fields-without-specifying-each-field/61631975#61631975)

But it still doesn't work.

I want to make a library for another company and still keep my access level modifiers fields and methods.

Proguard:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.example.mylibrary.Bedika {
 private <fields>;
}
-keep class com.example.mylibrary.Bedika {
 *;
}
```

My AAR library

```
public class Bedika {

private String stam;

public Bedika(String stam) {
 this.stam = stam;
}

public void print() {
 System.out.println(stam);
}
}
```

output after Proguard:

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

package com.example.mylibrary;

public class Bedika {
public String stam;

public Bedika(String var1) {
 this.stam = var1;
}

public void print() {
 System.out.println(this.stam);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like R8 is causing this issue and not `Proguard`.

Go into `gradle.properties`, and set `android.enableR8=false`. Next time you build, it will use `Proguard`.

R8 is Google's answer to Proguard and in the recent versions of The Android Gradle Plugin (3.4.0+) it defaults to R8's code shrinker/obfuscator. There are some pros and cons to using Google's version instead of Guardsquare's technology.

For more information, look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)

Answer (score 0):

You can usually add the `@Keep` annotation above the class or object (in Java or Kotlin). This is pretty self-explanatory, and will work.

Comment: I did it, and  i still get it public

    '//
    // Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
    // (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
    //

    package com.example.mylibrary;

    import androidx.annotation.Keep;

    @Keep
    public class Bedika {
       public String stam;

      public Bedika(String var1) {
         this.stam = var1;
      }

   
     public void print() {
         System.out.println(this.stam);
        }
    }'

Comment: Are you using consumerProguardFiles ?

Comment: nope, just pro-guard-rules in the library

Comment: What about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526173/obfuscate-private-fields-using-proguard

Comment: i need to use the consumerProguardFiles instead of the regular?

Comment: i tried it and it still doesn't work