# ProGuard convers private to public

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation

I have a class which has the following field

`private static final Identifier alTexture = new Identifier("al", "al.png");`

now when I obfuscate this with ProGuard I receive the following output

`public static final class_2960 vcAdmJHWywpfJDWjeu = new class_2960(SdtSesegrDtrPVCoeg.unscramble(51), SdtSesegrDtrPVCoeg.unscramble(398));`

as you can see its converting the private to public. The issue here is that this class requires the following to stay in private and I am unsure of what keeps it private in the options.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365021/how-to-tell-proguard-to-keep-private-fields-without-specifying-each-field

Comment: that did not work

Comment: Why do you need it to be private instead of public?  ProGuard generally assumes that it is given the whole program and that it can mess with it however it likes.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `-allowaccessmodification` option as per [Proguard manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage).